# Is is natural to say a "month has" something as an object?

Tags: expressions, possessives

I wrote an article analyzing trade figures for 2019. Originally I wrote: "We can find that only the first 3 months have their export values bigger than their import values". Upon proofreading, I was suggested to rephrase the "first 3 months have" part, because I was told that a month cannot possibly "have" something as an object that belongs to it.

I want to check if my original expression sounded natural to the native Americans or English speakers.

As a side note, I noticed a native expression that goes: "The last 3 months have seen significant development in the housing market." Perhaps this is relevant to my question here. 
I thought if an action word ("seen") can come right after "3 months", the "3 months" here can be regarded as a subject. If a subject can have an object, so do "3 months".

Comment: If there's something I would change about your sentence, it would be to remove *their*. Of course a month can have something. Doesn't the 4th of July belong to July? Your second sentence is different, though. It is not suggesting that the last 3 months have *had* something, but rather that they have *seen* something.

Comment: By the way, the second sentence is an example of personification. The author is not suggesting (and it would be incorrect to suggest) that the months have literally seen anything. It is an idiomatic way to express something the author and the target audience have witnessed occur over the course of those months.

Comment: Thanks, Micah. That was a boost of confidence to hear what you said, and thanks for the note on removing "their".

Comment: Not what you are asking about but "I was suggested to rephrase" is non-standard

Comment: Perhaps the 'their' is not necessary, but it sounds perfectly natural to my American English ears.

Comment: February has very sharp frosts. October has vivid leaf colours.

Comment: April *sees* a boom in house sales.

Comment: @Kevin Is it better if I said "I was advised to rephrase"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly OK to say that a month **has** something. There is an old poem that we use to remember the number of days in the month: the first couple of lines are:

> 30 days hath September, 
>    April, June and November...

Note that, when writing numbers that form a part of a sentence, we usually spell out numbers less than about twenty. Also, the word **their** isn't really required.

> We can find that only the first three months have export values bigger than import values.

Comment: "Note that, when writing numbers that form a part of a sentence, we usually spell out numbers less than about 20." As a Native English speaker, I did not know that. You truly do learn something new everyday!

Comment: Reading some time ago, I think it must have been in one of the two big guides - AP Style Book or Chicago Manual of Style, I saw the recommendation that one spell out numbers.  Interesting. Found an online reference that mentioned both. [According to this](https://apvschicago.com/2011/05/numbers-spell-out-or-use-numerals.html) it's spell out up to nine, spell out casual expressions (AP), or spell out any number up to 100 if it's followed by hundred or thousand or million, etc. I'd been using the rule of spell out up to nine, but missed the other ones.

Comment: It's interesting to know when to spell out numbers. I found an article of interest that digs a little deeper on this sub-topic as a reference for everyone: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/when-to-spell-out-numbers/

Comment: When I answered this question, I initially intended to write 'up to ten', but twelve is a definite candidate for writing as a word... and then fifteen... so I decided to err on the side of caution and put twenty. As @Yishmeray says, there are other cases, for example five thousand.

Comment: I was taught that numbers are spelled out, no matter how large, if they begin a sentence. "Thirty days hath September..." or "Three hundred sixty five days hath a year...", but "September has 30 days..." and "A year has 365 days...".

Comment: @Freeman. My 1991 Economist Style Guide says *"Never start a sentence with a figure, write the number in words instead. Use figures for numerals from 11 upwards, and for all numerals that include a decimal point or fraction. Use words for simple numerals from one to ten, except: in references to pages; in percentages; and in sets of numerals some of which are higher than ten."* So everyone here is more or less in agreement with The Economist.

Comment: Whether months possess ownership is only one of a cluster of queries there, Dean.
“We can find…” might just be used that way by native speakers but so very rarely, it would be better not to think about it.
“Only the first 3 months have their export values bigger than their import values" grates on the ear not because it gives the months the power of possession, nor even because it uses “their” but because it uses “their” twice.
“Only the first 3 months have export values bigger than their import values" would be the natural correction - and "greater" would be preferable to "bigger."

Comment: That was editing, not proof-reading. In every-day life most people will never meet either, yet broadly, "proof-reading" deals with typing errors, not writing style.

Comment: “The native Americans” always refers to indigenous peoples, even when it might be hoped "… or English speakers" made the context obvious.

Comment: Spelling out numbers is normal practice but most people never need to write numbers in narrative sentences and read them only in newspapers, for instance. When I wrote newspapers, we used letters up to and including ten, then numerals from 11… Other publishers’ house styles vary, and may be more logical

Comment: While I agree with your conclusion, the rhyme doesn't really provide evidence that months can 'have' a property which is not a property of the month itself, since being comprised of a certain number of days is intrinsic to the definition of a month. Compare 'A bicycle has two wheels' and 'these bicycles have a large export value', there's a jump between intrinsic, extrinsic properties then for the OP's case another jump from a property of something within a time period to saying that the property belongs to that time period - the value does not really belong to the month.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, the purpose of my answer was the refute the statement that "... a month cannot possibly "have" something as an object that belongs to it." and to demonstrate that it is natural to say that a month can "have" something. I think that my example satisfies both of these requirements. I think that it is unnecessary in this case to complicate matters by considering intrinsic and extrinsic properties.